# Poorly Scaling Rails ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following ActiveRecord query.  It ran fine when the number of messages was 50 in my test environment, but when we put it into production, and the number of messages grew to 5000, the response time was approaching 30 seconds.  Not good.

How can I do this query more efficiently, so keep it quick as the number of messages grows.  The query finds all the Alerts from all the Messages if they are not completed yet.

```
class AlertsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_user
  respond_to :json, :html

 def index
    @messages = current_user.messages.where(:active => true).order("created_at ASC")

    @alerts = Array.new
    @messages.each do |message|
        if (message.alerts.count > 0)
          @alerts = @alerts + message.alerts.where(:completed => false)
        end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

end


class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :message

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alerts, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: What kind of indexing are you using on your tables?

Comment: good catch - there's no index on the alerts table referencing the message.  will add it and update you on the performance.

Comment: As a note, using `[ ]` to create an empty array is more traditional than using `Array.new`. Also you can use `+=` to add things to an array instead of `@array = @array + ...`.

Comment: I would make sure that `user_id` in your messages table has an index on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off of Jesse's answer, a little bit better would be to create a scope to only select the `pending_alerts`, this way you're passing less data around, and letting the database do more of the work.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :pending_alerts, lambda {
    alerts.where(:completed => false)
  }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
@messages = current_user.messages.includes(:pending_alerts).where(:active => true).order("created_at ASC")  
@alerts = @messages.map { |m| m.alerts }
```

Comment: ohhhh nice. I like the idea of including a scope; hadn't ever trie that!

Comment: If you use a particular set of conditions more than once, it's almost always a good idea to define a `scope` for them.

Comment: You don't really need a lambda in this particular case. You can just say: scope :pending_alerts, joins(:alerts).where("alerts.completed = false")

Comment: Salil, you're right, however in Rails 4 this syntax will likely be deprecated, so I think it would be prudent to leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a n+1 problem. Documentation here (search for [Solution to N + 1 queries problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html))

```
@messages = current_user.messages.includes(:alerts).where(:active => true).order("created_at ASC")
```

Then to make the @alerts simpler:

```
@alerts = @messages.map do |message|
  message.alerts.select {|alert| !alert.completed}
end
```

Comment: Instead of doing a `select` on the alerts fetched, why not pass through a condition that excludes them in the first place?

Comment: Trying your second block, I get this error - Showing <i>app/views/alerts/index.json.rabl</i> where line <b>#1</b> raised:
  <pre><code>can't convert Array into Hash</code></pre>

Comment: @tadman I like the pending_alerts scope from chrismohr for your suggestion

Comment: @bluedevil2k That's a rabl view error, not sure it's related to the `@alerts` array.